# How Does GetSchemaTable() Work?

Tags: c#, oledbdatareader, getschematable

```
OleDbDataReader oleDbDataReader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
DataTable dataTable = oleDbDataReader.GetSchemaTable();
```

How does `GetSchemaTable()` work?

Where does it get its information in RDBMS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implementation of `IDataReader.GetSchemaTable()` is up to the provider - so it will vary. You can write your own providers and do it any way you want.

To be honest this is bad bit of design in the framework - you should never have interface methods that return an untyped `DataTable` or `DataSet` as that result could contain anything. Kinda defeats the point of constraining it by an interface in the first place: *"you must have a method that returns `DataTable` but we don't care what rows or columns it has"*

Even if the provider is SQL `GetSchemaTable()` doesn't go back to the `[syscolumns]` or `[sysobjects]`. That would be an additional DB call, require additional privileges and not work anyway, as the result set doesn't need to reflect any objects in the DB.

I'm not certain, but I'd expect the vast majority of `IDataReader.GetSchemaTable()` implementations to read some properties of the meta data held with the result set.

Answer (score 2):

GetSchemaTable() reads the metadata on the resultset returned by ADO.NET.

Answer (score -1):

From the system tables (e.g., syscolumns, sysobjects, etc) in each database.

Comment: Is this always the case, or does that depend on the OLE DB provider being used?

Comment: That's wrong. The result might be dynamic, a user might have no permission to view sysobjects (VIEW DEFINITION in MSSQL 2005+) etc.

Comment: Suppose your reader was across `SELECT 'test', 1`? You could call `GetSchemaTable()` on the `IDataReader` result set and it definitely wouldn't be checking `[sysobjects]`.